# Fish function creates random file

Tags: git, fish

I created a fish shell function to shorten the "git add" process for me (cause it's so long):

```
function ga
    if count $argv > 0
        git add $argv
    else
        git add .
    end
end
```

It works just fine, adding the whole directory if I call it without arguments, and adding only specific files if I name those, with one very weird exception:

*Using "ga" instead of "git add", with or without arguments, creates a file name "0" in the directory. Its contents are generally a single number (0 or 2).*

Any idea what's going on here? It's totally bizarre, and a real pain, because I like the function, but don't want to keep pushing up empty "0" files to repos to which I contribute.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That `>` isn't doing a comparison, it's output redirection. That is, it's taking the output of

```
count $argv
```

and writing it into a file called `0`.  You probably want something like:

```
function ga
    if [ (count $argv) -gt 0 ]
        git add $argv
    else
        git add .
    end
end
```

Comment: Awesome. Life saver. I'd been messing that up all over the place.

Comment: Also to reduce other confusion, `[` is a binary and not any syntax magic related to fish. You could also use the function `test`, which would be written like `if test (count $argv) -gt 0`